# Linear transformation and dependence of vectors

Tags: linear-transformations

I couldn't find an example or explanation why the following sentence is correct

If a Transformation is linear, and vectors $u_1$,$u_2$,$u_3$ are dependent then 
$T(u_1)$,$T(u_2)$,$T(u_3)$
must also be dependent

**but**

If a Transformation is linear, and $T(u_1)$,$T(u_2)$,$T(u_3)$ are dependent , that doesn't mean vectors $u_1$,$u_2$,$u_3$ are dependent

Couldn't think of an example that would justify the 2nd phrase

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the null function and take any $3$ linear independent vectors $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$. Then $\bigl\{T(u_1),T(u_2),T(u_3)\bigr\}$ is linearly dependent (since it is equal to $\{0\}$).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give another example after José Carlos Santos' answer:

Take $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$ which is linear and $e_1,e_2,e_3$ the usual bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $T(e_1)=e_1,T(e_2)=e_2,T(e_3)=\mathbf{0}$ which are dependent whereas $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are independent.

**EDIT**

Suppose that $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are dependent so the are $s_1,s_2,s_3\in \mathbb{R}$ (actually they belong to the field on which your vector space is over) not all $=0$ such that
$$s_1u_1+s_2u_2+s_3u_3=0\Rightarrow$$ $$ T(s_1u_1+s_2u_2+s_3u_3)=T(0)=0\Rightarrow s_1T(u_1)+s_2T(u_2)+s_3T(u_3)=0$$

so $T(u_1),T(u_2),T(u_3)$ are dependent.

Comment: Thank you, care to explain the general idea behind the 1st part of the phrase mate?

Comment: @Lostdawn Do you mean the phrase "If a Transformation is linear, and vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$  are dependent then $T(u_1),T(u_2),T(u_3)$ must also be dependent" ?

Comment: yea, im not sure how to "prove" that the phrase is always correct

Comment: @Lostdawn I' ll write it in the main answer.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome!